# SWT.ICON_WARNING fit to a button

Tags: java, image, swt

I have the following code:

```
final Image img = getShell().getDisplay().getSystemImage(SWT.ICON_WARNING);
btnWarning.setImage(img);
```

This work perfect on Windows, but it doesn't work on Mac, because the image doesn't fit in.

Look like this:

[image: Picture of the button]

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Well what do you want to do? Reduce the size of the image or increase the height of the button?

Comment: manipulate the size of the image. It's a new button on the app, and it's size equal to other buttons. If there aren't any way to do this without re-size the button, it's possible.

Comment: I fixed this problem by changing the icon to a new one from a free icon set found on the internet, but still wonder if there's an other way or not.